# Receiving webhooks PHP "&contact[uid]="

Tags: php, curl, webhooks

I need to receive a webhook, I have written a script to receive it and write to a database and all works apart from the fields that have `[]` in them.

e.g this is the string I receive:

> (event=message&token=54dgr54rg54df35g4f564534g65df4g&contact[uid]=7523256254&contact[name]=Tim&contact[type]=user)

I can use `($event = $_POST[event])` and that works fine but when I try `($cus_uid = $_POST['custom[uid]'])` it does not work becasue it has the `[]` in it.

How can I receive this `($cus_uid = $_POST['custom[uid]'])`?

I tried with `file_get_contents` but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

`foo[bar]` is parsed by PHP into an array. The result is accessible via `$_POST['foo']['bar']`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access these values treating them as array:

```
$cus_id = $_POST['contact']['uid'];
```